# Sql condition return 1 if column has x and y

Tags: sql-server

I have to check if in my table it has 2 records like this

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE ID = 10 AND x IN ('S','R') )
```

Problem is that this query will return 1 if it has just a single value of these,

I also tried with a simple AND

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE ID = 10 AND x = 'S' AND x ='R' )
```

This won't return 1 if these values exist

The ideal is that I can return 1 if if in the column those 2 values exist but can't figure out how to do it

Comment: this doesn't work because the WHERE clause evaluates each row individually in turn and applies the criteria to that row specifically, then moves to the next one, it does not examine all the rows at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do aggregation :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM myTable 
           WHERE ID = 10 AND x IN( 'R', 'S')
           GROUP BY ID
           HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT x) = 2
           )
```

However, `DISTINCT` would be redundant if `ID` has unique `X`'s.

If you want to select data only then you can write :

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM myTable mt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable mt1 WHERE mt1.ID = mt.ID AND mt1.x = 'R') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable mt2 WHERE mt2.ID = mt.ID AND mt2.x = 'S');
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what i wanted